# Show PDF without saving it with itext 7 and vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, itext7

I currently have the following code, which opens a PDF file and has fillable fields, saves it to a path, and then displays it on the screen (Adobe Reader). What I currently want is to open the PDF, pass the data to it and just display it either in a browser or in Adobe Reader without the need to save it to the local disk.

```html
Dim destino = "C:\generacion\ejemplo.pdf"
Dim leerpdf = "C:\plantillas\plantilla.pdf"
Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(leerpdf)
Dim writer As PdfWriter = New PdfWriter(CStr(destino))
Dim PdfDocument As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(reader, writer)
Dim form As iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(PdfDocument, False)
form.GetField("dato1").SetValue(nombre)
form.GetField("dato2").SetValue(direccion)
form.GetField("dato3").SetValue(telefono)
form.FlattenFields()
PdfDocument.Close()
Process.Start(destino)
```

Comment: You need to explain exactly what _I have not had positive results_ means.  Exceptions, unexpected behaviours or something else?  That aside, what's wrong with downloading it to a temp file?

Comment: Currently I have a physical PDF file which I pass data such as name, address, etc. And after editing it with itext I would like to show this new PDF file in the browser without the need to save it on the local disk